# how to get class instance type signature

Tags: typescript

I have to pass a structure of pages to my core object and then have this pages available in there with auto-completion. Here is my working case:

```
interface Adapter{}
interface PageInterface{}

type PageCtor = {new(adapter: Adapter): PageInterface}
class BasePage implements PageInterface{
  constructor(public adapter: Adapter) {}
}
class LoginPage extends BasePage{
  name: string = 'login'
  foo: number
  constructor(public adapter: Adapter) {
    super(adapter)
  }
  go() {
    console.log('Yo, logged in')
  }
}
class LogoutPage extends BasePage{}
class AboutPage extends BasePage{}

class PagesConfig {[key: string]: PageCtor}

type BaseCore<T> = {[key in keyof T]?: T[key]}

class Core<T>{
  pages: BaseCore<T> = {}
  constructor(public adapter: Adapter, pages: PagesConfig) {
    Object.entries(pages).map(([key, value]: [string, PageCtor]) => {
      (this.pages as any)[key] = new value(adapter)
    })
  }
}

interface Pages{
  login: LoginPage
  logout: LogoutPage
  about: AboutPage
}

class CurrentPages{
  [key: string]: PageCtor
  login = LoginPage
  logout = LogoutPage
  about = AboutPage
}


const adapter = {} as Adapter

const core = new Core<Pages>(adapter, new CurrentPages())
```

in this case the end-user of my `Core` class should provide `Pages` interface and `CurrentPages` class which looks like some king of duplication. Each time end-user of my class would need to add new page, he should add it in two places. How can this be simplified with only `CurrentPages` class or some other way?

I think this have something to do with type `BaseCore` signature:

```
type BaseCore<T> = {[key in keyof T]?: T[key]}
```

here, `T[key]` would be a class constructor in my case, how do I change it to be a class instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prevent the duplication, but only if you drop the index signature from `CurrentPages`. The index signature hide mapping of any other members.

You can then use the `InstanceType` conditional type to get the instance type from a class type:

```
type BaseCore<T extends Record<string, PageCtor>> = { [key in keyof T]?: InstanceType<T[key]> }

class Core<T extends Record<keyof T, PageCtor>>{
    pages: BaseCore<T> = {}
    constructor(public adapter: Adapter, pages: T) {
        Object.entries(pages).map(([key, value]) => {
            (this.pages as any)[key] = new (value as PageCtor)(adapter)
        })
    }
}

class CurrentPages {
    login = LoginPage
    logout = LogoutPage
    about = AboutPage
}


const adapter = {} as Adapter

const core = new Core(adapter, new CurrentPages())
core.pages.about;
core.pages.login;
core.pages.logon; //err
```

Comment: seems like this work even with index signature in `CurrentPages` - https://imgur.com/a/H5FLoor